# Solve $4 \times2^x+3^x=5^x$ without any sort of calculator

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponentiation

Is there a way i can solve the following equation only by using high school mathematics?
$$4 \times2^x+3^x=5^x$$

I tried writing $5$ as $2+3$ but didn't get any result.

After that i tried to divide by $5^x$ and see how the function goes, but, unfortunately didn't got me somewhere either.

Comment: i tried writing 5 as 2+3 ,but didnt get any result.After that i tried to divide by $$5^x$$ and see how the function goes,but ,unfortunately didnt got me somewhere either.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming $x$ to be natural,
$$
5^x-3^x=(5-3)(5^{x-1}+3\cdot5^{x-2}+3^2\cdot5^{x-3}+\cdots+3^{x-1})=4\cdot2^x\\
\implies (5^{x-1}+3\cdot5^{x-2}+3^2\cdot5^{x-3}+\cdots+3^{x-1})=4\cdot2^{x-1}
$$
Each term in LHS looks like $3^{n}5^{x-1-n}>2^n2^{x-1-n}=2^{x-1}$.

There are $x$ number of terms in LHS. If there are $4$ or more terms in LHS, each of them would be greater than $2^{x-1}$ and the equation would not hold. So $1\le x\le 3$. Manually checking $x=1,2,3$ we see $x=2$ is a solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Divide both sides by $5^x$, and notice that the left side is strictly decreasing, since it is the sum of two strictly decreasing functions, and the right side is constant. It follows that our equation has at most one solution. Can you find it ? ;-$)$

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, only that i wanted to divide by 3^x so i would have the right side increasing and the left side decreasing. Thabk you for your answer!

Comment: The LHS is a strictly *decreasing* function, since both 4 * (2 / 5)^x and (3 / 5)^x are strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Analyse this  function and try to prove  $x=2$ is only solution  $$f\left( x \right) =4\cdot 2^{ x }+3^{ x }-5^{ x }$$

Comment: Wanted to get my first answer here, but this was already here :)

Comment: you can still  post it more detaily,i have just gaven  a hint)

Answer (score 2):

You tried to use $2+3=5$ to no avail. A slightly different "flash of insight" approach would be to invoke Pythagoras: $3^2+4^2=5^2$.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it was rather simple if you use the logarithm rules. I must have made a mistake somewhere since I am getting x = -1. Maybe my method will be helpful though so I'm posting it here:

First step: take the 3^x to RHS;

Second step: use logarithms on both sides;

Third step: rewrite 4 as 2^2 (hence your LHS is log ( 2^(2+x))   );

Fourth step: use logarithm rule on RHS thus obtain (2+x)*log(2)
;

Fifht step: use logarithm rules on LHS : log(5^x - 3^x) = log(5^x)/log(3^x) = (x * log5)/ (x * log3). The x of course cancels hence we have log5/log3;

Sixth step: divide both sides by log(2) hence your RHS = 2+x and your LHS = log5 / (log2 * log3). yet again apply log rule to the LHS hence we have log5/log5 which is 1 but then we end up with x+2 = 1 hence the x = -1. 
This is obviously not the case since it can easily be shown by plugging in x = -1 that it's not the equation.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer.At the fifth step i do belive there is a mistake. log(b)-log(a)=log(b/a)

Comment: Oh you are right, that step is not allowed. Silly mistake. In that case it's rather more complicated since I cannot think of a way to show log(5^x - 3^x) / log2 is 4 without knowing already that it is indeed 4.

Comment: You could potentially assign your log base a value then attempt to solve it by using log base rules though I'm not convinced it will work smoothly, if at all.